# Where Can I Find an Inexpensive Bike Stand Clamp

Tags: repair, tools

Are there any recommendations for where I can buy an inexpensive bike stand clamp? I do not know what they are exactly called but the actual part that the bicycle is held onto in a work stand.

Comment: Do you mean a work stand - something to hold the bike steady while you work on it?

Comment: Seconding Tommy's comment:  http://goo.gl/XC7SX  workstand.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: @anton2g: it's unclear what you're asking about, and you don't even use the same word in the title and body. Please use more detail to describe what you're looking for.  What's a workstation clip/slip for?

Comment: I am not referring to the whole stand, just the clip part. AKA the actual part that the bicycle is held onto by.

Comment: @anton2g I took the liberty of editing your question extensively based on the questions and the response in the comments - feel free to fix my edits or roll back if my changes were not to your liking. And...Welcome to Bicycles.SE; be sure to check out the FAQ http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for just the clamp, and want something produced commercially you are going to have a hard time finding something inexpensive (at least by my budget).  A Google search for Park Repair Clamp turns up a number of options but they are generally $100 and up.  You can pick up a decent stand for that much.

The best deal I could find was a brand I'd never heard of:

[Sette Workbench Stand](http://www.mtbr.com/cat/accessories/tools/sette/torx-st-115-workbench-mount-workstand/prd_415723_152crx.aspx) (or this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sette+Torx+ST+115+Work+Bench+Mount+Workstand))

[image: Sette Workbench Stand]

Your other option would be to build your own stand:

[DIY Bench Mount Bike Repair Stand](http://www.instructables.com/id/PVC-Bench-top-Bike-Repair-Stand/)

[Work Bench Repair Stand with Angle Adjustment](http://www.instructables.com/id/Work-Bench-Bike-repair-stand-with-angle-adjustment/)

Hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but I agree $100 is a bit much. Nothing cheaper then the Sette?

Comment: Not that I've found - but there are several DIY options, including finding an old car rack and using the arms, or even just attaching 2x4's with notches in them to your bench or wall studs.  Check out the stand links above, and the related links on those pages.

Comment: @anton2g I just noticed the price on the Sette stand is $55 as of today, FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

If you really are looking for a cheap option, plumbers supply shops will have cheap clamps used for holding pipes for bending.

B&Q here has one that looks reasonable and suitable for about £60. Basically seems like a standard vice with wooden face plates that have curved grooves for pipes.

Answer (score 3):

If the clamp in [Gary's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6099/where-can-i-find-an-inexpensive-bike-stand-clamp/6104#6104) is too pricey, it's time to start looking at other options than an actual clamp.

Even though it's nowhere nearly as flexible as a proper repair stand, a **wall mount bike rack** works quite wall as a repair stand. You screw one of these into the wall at shoulder height (or whatever height you like) and put the bike in it, drivetrain-side out. You now have a decent repair stand - the pedals will rotate freely if there's nothing on the wall to prevent it. (Check the depth of the stand before buying, though.) These go for about $25 at most hardware stores.

[image: wall-mountable repair stand]

Also, a **car rack** will do a decent job as a repair stand. These generally cost almost as much as that stand, so do this if you already have a car rack or if you find one really cheap.

The pedals often do not rotate freely on these, however, unless the bike is all the way out from the car. You want the sort of rack where the bikes hang from the rack, not the kind where the bikes stand on top of the rack. Look for a 3-bike rack or more, those tend to protrude out from the car more. Working on your bike when it's on your car can scratch your car or get it dirty, so this isn't an option on that bright yellow sports car.

**Floor stands** also work fairly wall, but have many of the same limitations as car racks; they're almost always not deep enough for the pedals to rotate freely.

Answer (score 2):

Find a decent pair of medium vice grips, and weld a pipe approximately 1-3/8 diameter by 3" length, (you'll have to cut into 2 equal halves by cutting down the 3" length), weld 1 of the the halves onto the upper and the other1to the  the lower jaws of the vice grips perpendicular to the pliers. You attach to whatever piece of stand-off arm by welding, clamping, whatever. I built my bike stand from parts thrown away by local businesses. The lower stand is made from a collapsible P.A. monitor stand, that is adjustibe by width of the3 outrigger "feet", and adjusts to 5' high from26". The center section is made from a steel adjustable telescoping floor vacuum pipe. The top section is from a drum riser and several pieces of hardware/ clamps made for the drums, cymbals. I am currently working on some seatpost clamps, but am currently using handlebar end "antlers"  wrapped with foam grips. The stand holds 2 mountain bikes and it's not even a bit strained.

Comment: Good answer.  When you get a bit more reputation you can come back and add a photo.  Another good source of strong pipe is old trampolines, and they tend to have useful bends too.

Comment: I find angle iron works less badly, because unless the round pipe closely matches the size of the tube you're clamping it doesn't work well. But I quickly decided that paying for a Park clamp and making my own stand was a better idea. To save money you could look for a second hand clamp from a workstand, as cheap workstands often fail leaving a usable clamp.

Answer (score 1):

In Europe, Lidl has complete bike stands for less than 30 Eur. I guess you could take just clamp from it if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Can you weld?   Some of these homemade efforts work really well, and will last many decades longer than plasticky ones.

[image]

Full detail http://www.cycletrailers.co.nz/html/bike_workstands.html

Or here's someone else's idea
[image]

http://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-bike-repair-stand/

[image]
Finally here's what I made, usiog some old scaffolding cross braces.  Theres an old concrete umbrella stand at the bottom of the pole, and all my tools can sit in the rear of the car for easier access.  Only problem is the bike wobbles about if you're leaning on a spanner, but it provides easy access without bending down.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon bicycle clamps for car racks, which are in the range of 30-40 euro:

[image][image]

Perhaps these are helpful as well? I found them by doing a web search for "Thule frame clamp", but I'm sure there are other brands as well.